# How can I reference a file in my servlet, located inside my tomcat project without its full path

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

I want to reference a file located in the some parent directory of my servlet. I have a tomcat poject created via intellij (hence the running program is in war_exploded file). I want the servlet to reference a file located in ../../../input/prototypes. The file structure is:

```
MyProject
   ..input
      ..prototypes
         myfile.xlsx (file I want to ref)

   ..out
      ..production
      ..artifacts
         ..Public_war_exploded (running dir)

   ..src
   ..web
```

When I try to reference the file as ..\\..\\..\\input\\prototypes\\myfile.xlsx I get an FileNotFound error. How can I reference that file without using the full path ?

The servlet code is:

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
          ReadXL inpXL = new ReadXL("..\\..\\..\\input\\prototypes\\prototype.xlsx");
   }
```

ReadXL:

```
public class ReadXL {        
        public ReadXL(String path) throws IOException{
            this.openXL(path);
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    
        private void openXL(String path) throws IOException{
            xlFile = new File(path);
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
    
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); // get workbook
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // extract first (and only) page
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the servlet code snippet?

Comment: Just did @SergeyVasnev

Comment: Perhaps you should externalize configuration info such as this file system path, rather than hard-coding within your Java code. You can use Tomcat’s JNDI features to load the file path at runtime. See [this HOWTO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Generic_JavaBean_Resources).

Comment: Remark that a relative path as the one you use is resolved against the current directory of the Tomcat process. The current directory of a Tomcat server is not well defined and shouldn't be used. Pass the path to your file as a parameter to your request.